# How to speed up photo insertion from google drive to html page

Tags: javascript, image, google-drive-api

I have photos in a folder on google drive....The folder is shared to be used by anyone on the web .

I have a table in a static html page on my computer and i set the background of the cell using javascript as below

document.getElementById("ImageCell").style.backgroundImage=url("https://drive.google.com/uc?id=xxxx");

This works fine.

I have 20 photos per page and when i use window.print() it takes a while to load and the main issue is sometimes it does not render and i see memory usage up to 100%.

So looks like this is memory intensive.

My question is- is there any better method of implementation which will not be so slow.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Google Drive was ever meant to function as a CDN.  Are there too many photos for you to just bundle them up with your site?

If so, look into dumping them into an S3 bucket on Amazon, and caching them with cloudfront.